# network native module android not working in react-native progam for android while working on android studio program

Tags: android, service, react-native

I have not too much experience with android services, the broadcastReceiver have some warning also `WifiReceiver.java` uses or overrides a deprecated API. I search for this but couldn't find any solution, I don't know which one method is deprecated, I m not in touch too much with java and android

Here is error

```
cannot find symbol
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver,filter);
        ^
  symbol:   variable registerReceiver
```

My react Method is

```
@ReactMethod
    public void NetInfo(){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
        filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        WifiReceiver wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver,filter);
    }
```

and broadcast receiver is

```
    public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
        private Context mContext;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            mContext = context;


            if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI &&
                        networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    // Wifi is connected
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();

                    Log.e(TAG, " -- Wifi connected --- " + " SSID " + ssid );
                    Toast.makeText(context, " -- Wifi connected --- " + " SSID " + ssid , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))
            {
                int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
                if (wifiState == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Status changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

getting this note also,

> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Answer (score 2):

use with react application content `reactContext.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(args here)`